# SQLDF How to append the new vetors?

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, sqldf

see I have a data.frame like this:

```
str(veh)
$VEHAGE  int  3 6 35 35 5 3 7 4 5 1 ...
$VEHTYPE int  2 1 3 1 2 3 1 4 2 3 ...
```

then I run

```
a<-sqldf("SELECT VEHAGE, COUNT(VEHAGE) as count1
                             FROM veh 
                             WHERE VEHTYPE==1
                             GROUP BY VEHAGE")


a<-sqldf("SELECT VEHAGE, COUNT(VEHAGE) as count234
                             FROM veh 
                             WHERE VEHTYPE==2|3|4
                             GROUP BY VEHAGE")
```

I get a result like this

```
head(a)
  VEHAGE count234
1     -9     92
2      1     79
3      2    164
4      3    212
5      4    260
6      5    199
```

I lost count1 in this case. But I want a head(a) like this

```
  VEHAGE count1   count234
1     -9     92    510
2      1     79    844
3      2    164    123
4      3    212    123
5      4    260    100
6      5    199    100
```

Any Idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You overwrite `a` when you call `sqldf` the second time. That's why you lose `count1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for this:

```
# first query
a <- sqldf("SELECT VEHAGE, COUNT(VEHAGE) as count1
                             FROM veh 
                             WHERE VEHTYPE==1
                             GROUP BY VEHAGE")

# second query
b <- sqldf("SELECT VEHAGE, COUNT(VEHAGE) as count234
                             FROM veh 
                             WHERE VEHTYPE IN (2, 3, 4)
                             GROUP BY VEHAGE")

# combine
a <- sqldf("SELECT * 
            FROM a JOIN b
            USING (VEHAGE)")
```

Comment: I think you have to `merge` in case the two groups have different number of rows (e.g. some VEHTYPE==1 may be of ages unique to that group).

Comment: @BrodieG Thanks for pointing this out. I changed my approach.

Comment: Thank you both. It works! Yes, I should to merge since some group has no age -9, the combine function works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
a<-sqldf(
 "SELECT VEHAGE, 
    SUM(if(VEHTYPE==1, 1, 0)) as count1,
    SUM(if(VEHTYPE==2|3|4, 1, 0)) as count234
  FROM veh 
  GROUP BY VEHAGE")
```

Though disclaimer, I'm not familiar with `sqldf` syntax, but something like this would work in MySQL (though in MySQL `==2|3|4` would have to be `in(2, 3, 4)`).

Also, you may want to add something like `HAVING count1 | count234` to get rid of the `VEHAGE`s with no vehicles in those categories.

Comment: The SQL syntax used by sqldf depends on the back end you are using.  By default it uses SQLite but can also use H2, MySQL and PostgreSQL.